# How to create this simple gif animation with Diagrams

Tags: haskell

I am trying to understand how to use Diagrams library in Haskell.

Here is my attempt at making a simple gif animation which switches between two circles of radii 1 and 2. I tried to mimic what I saw on

Here is the code, I tried.

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
import Diagrams.Backend.SVG.CmdLine
import Diagrams.Prelude

delays = take 2 (repeat 3)

gif :: [(Diagram B, Int)]
gif = zip [circle 1, circle 2] delays

main = mainWith $ gif
```

But this fails to compile! The errors I get are

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( maze.hs, maze.o )

maze.hs:10:8:
    No instance for (Diagrams.Backend.CmdLine.Parseable
                       (Diagrams.Backend.CmdLine.MainOpts
                          [(QDiagram B V2 Double Any, Int)]))
      arising from a use of ‘mainWith’
    In the expression: mainWith
    In the expression: mainWith $ gif
    In an equation for ‘main’: main = mainWith $ gif
```

Where am I going wrong in the code above?

Comment: Instead of `take 2 (repeat x)` you can use `replicate 2 x`.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner: or just `repeat x` in this case, since the `zip` will take care of truncating it to just the right length.

Comment: @Cactus Or simply `map (\d -> (d,3))`, since `zip`ing with a constant list is overkill.

Comment: @joachimbreitner or use `TupleSections` and `map (,3)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me a moment to figure it out, because the error message is not obvious at all, but it's a backend problem. [The documentation](http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/doc/manual.html#animated-gifs) states that the cairo backend can create animated gif. However, you are using the svg backend (which is unable to understand what `[(Diagram B, Int)]` is.

To solve this, make sure you have the `diagrams-cairo` package installed, and change the line

```
import Diagrams.Backend.SVG.CmdLine
```

to

```
import Diagrams.Backend.Cairo.CmdLine
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your suggestion, and it did compile. I ran it with `./main -o output.gif -w 400` But the resulting gif file was just a large black square: no circles were shown. Did you have the same problems on your computer?

Comment: @smilingbuddha: it seems the Gif backend defaults to black background and foreground; if you use e.g. `circle  1 # lc white` then you'll see a white outline of a circle on a black background.

Comment: @Cactus Oh I see. Thanks!!! I tried add `# white` to both elements of my array. But now I only see a single white circle, on a black background. I wanted the animation to keep switching between the two white circles.

Answer (score 3):

I'll explain the other steps necessary, since this is one of the first search results for doing animations in diagrams. Diagrams rescales the viewport to the image size for each circle, so that `circle 1` and `circle 2` are equivalent. To solve this you can lay the circles on invisible squares of the same size as `circle 2`. 
Also the delays are given in 1/100 seconds. The correct code would then be:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
import Diagrams.Backend.Cairo.CmdLine
import Diagrams.Prelude

gif :: [(Diagram B, Int)]
gif = map (\x -> (x # lc white <> square 4 # lw none,300)) [circle 1,circle 2]

main = mainWith gif
```